# npm Error: Cannot find module './core/util'

Tags: npm

The error occurs on no other machine. Tried to reinstall Node, node_modules folder and the whole project.

node_module/core/util does not exist, however there is core-util-is and core-js. Not sure if that is related somehow.

```
Error: Cannot find module './core/util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Paul\WebstormProjects\cryptarbi\server.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./core/util` is required in your `C:\Users\Paul\WebstormProjects\cryptarbi\server.js` file

If your requiring `util` from a file, the path is wrong. Or, as you said it is happening in only one machine, I suspect it is a soft link issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have the folder `src/core/util`, the server.js files sais `const util = require('./core/util');`
Is something wrong here? Tried to change require to `/src/core/util` but did not work either

Comment: you have to give the relative path to `util` with respect to `server.js`, can you provide the file hierarchy for both `util` and `server.js`?

Comment: I moved it core/util from src to root and now it is working, thank you for your input.